# Delphi GetLogicalProcessorInformation x64

Tags: delphi, 64-bit

Strangely this code that works well under Delphi X32 does not work when compiled x64.
The first call to GetLogicalProcessorInformation simply return code 988 (Invalid access to memory location) and i wonder why, and what could be achieved to overcome this.

```
function GetLogicalProcessorInfo : TLogicalProcessorInformation;
var
  i           : Integer;
  ReturnLength: DWORD;
  Buffer      : array of TSystemLogicalProcessorInformation;

begin

  result.LogicalProcessorCount := 0;
  result.NumaNodeCount         := 0;
  result.ProcessorCoreCount    := 0;
  result.ProcessorL1CacheCount := 0;
  result.ProcessorL2CacheCount := 0;
  result.ProcessorL3CacheCount := 0;
  result.ProcessorPackageCount := 0;

  SetLength(Buffer,256);

  if not GetLogicalProcessorInformation(@Buffer[0], ReturnLength) then
  begin
    if GetLastError = ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER then
    begin
      SetLength(Buffer,ReturnLength div SizeOf(TSystemLogicalProcessorInformation) + 1);
      if not GetLogicalProcessorInformation(@Buffer[0], ReturnLength) then
        RaiseLastOSError;
    end
    else
      RaiseLastOSError;
  end;

  SetLength(Buffer, ReturnLength div SizeOf(TSystemLogicalProcessorInformation));

  for i := 0 to High(Buffer) do begin
    case Buffer[i].Relationship of
        RelationNumaNode: Inc(result.NumaNodeCount);
        RelationProcessorCore:
          begin
            Inc(result.ProcessorCoreCount);
            result.LogicalProcessorCount := result.LogicalProcessorCount + CountSetBits(Buffer[i].ProcessorMask);
          end;
        RelationCache:
          begin
            if (Buffer[i].Cache.Level = 1) then Inc(result.ProcessorL1CacheCount)
            else if (Buffer[i].Cache.Level = 2) then Inc(result.ProcessorL2CacheCount)
            else if (Buffer[i].Cache.Level = 3) then Inc(result.ProcessorL3CacheCount);
          end;
        RelationProcessorPackage: Inc(result.ProcessorPackageCount);
        else
          raise Exception.Create('Error: Unsupported LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_RELATIONSHIP value.');
    end;
  end;

end;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not initializing `ReturnLength` with the size of your `Buffer` before the 1st call to `GetLogicalProcessorInformation()`, causing **undefined behavior**.  That parameter is an in/out parameter, per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getlogicalprocessorinformation):

> ReturnedLength
>
> **On input, specifies the length of the buffer pointed to by `Buffer`, in bytes.** If the buffer is large enough to contain all of the data, this function succeeds and `ReturnLength` is set to the number of bytes returned. If the buffer is not large enough to contain all of the data, the function fails, `GetLastError` returns `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER`, and `ReturnLength` is set to the buffer length required to contain all of the data. If the function fails with an error other than `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER`, the value of `ReturnLength` is undefined.

You need to add that initial value, eg:

```pascal
SetLength(Buffer,256);

ReturnLength := SizeOf(TSystemLogicalProcessorInformation) * 256; // <-- ADD THIS!

if not GetLogicalProcessorInformation(@Buffer[0], ReturnLength) then
...
```

It is a fluke that your code works at all under 32bit.  Chances are, `ReturnLength` simply picks up a *random value* off the call stack that happened to allow `GetLogicalProcessorInformation()` to operate without causing an `ERROR_NOACCESS` (998) error.  Literally *anything* can happen when you invoke *undefined behavior*, including seemingly correct behavior.

Comment: You found it. I missed that it was that this parameter is an in/out parameter.... It works fine now.

Comment: Thanks a lot Remy !